# Using find_all in BS4 to get text as a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, discord

I'll start by saying I'm very new with Python. I've been building a Discord bot with discord.py and Beautiful Soup 4. Here's where I'm at:

```
@commands.command(hidden=True)
async def roster(self):
    """Gets a list of CD's members"""
    url = "http://www.clandestine.pw/roster.html"
    async with aiohttp.get(url) as response:
        soupObject = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "html.parser")
    try:
        text = soupObject.find_all("font", attrs={'size': '4'})
        await self.bot.say(text)
    except:
        await self.bot.say("Not found!")
```

Here's the output:
[image: http://puu.sh/uycBF/1efe173437.png]

Now, I've tried using `get_text()` in multiple different ways to strip the brackets and HTML tags from this code, but it throws an error each time. How would I be able to either achieve that or output this data into an array or list and then just print the plain text?

Comment: Which version of python and beautiful soup are you using? I'm assuming it's >= python 3.5 given the async await syntax

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
text = soupObject.find_all("font", attrs={'size': '4'})
```

with this:

```
all_font_tags = soupObject.find_all("font", attrs={'size': '4'})
list_of_inner_text = [x.text for x in all_font_tags]
# If you want to print the text as a comma separated string
text = ', '.join(list_of_inner_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a list of `Tags` from BeautifulSoup, the brackets you are seing are from the list object.

Either return them as a list of strings:

```
 text = [Member.get_text().encode("utf-8").strip() for Member in soup.find_all("font", attrs={'size': '4'}) if not Member.get_text().encode("utf-8").startswith("\xe2")]
```

Or a single string:

```
text = ",".join([Member.get_text().encode("utf-8") for Member in soup.find_all("font", attrs={'size': '4'}) if not Member.get_text().encode("utf-8").startswith("\xe2")])
```