# Python discord bot - coroutine was never awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a Discord bot and it works to some degree but it keeps crashing every couple minutes. It gives me an error like

> Task was detroyed but it's pending

I came across the information that I had to get rid of my `response = request.get(url)` and replace it with `async with aiohttp.get(url) as response`.

Now when I have it like this, it gives me

> coroutine 'availability' was never awaited"

To solve this I think I have to use some sort of loop, but how exactly do I need to do this?

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
import aiohttp
import async_timeout

async def availability():
    url = "some url"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession().get(url, headers=headers) as response:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        print(soup)
        return soup

Client = discord.Client()
bot_prefix= "?"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

availible = True

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Online!")
    print("Name: {}".format(client.user.name))
    print("ID: {}".format(client.user.id))

    bessie = 0
    waittime = 0

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if wachttijd == 0:
            if ("0 available") not in str(availability()):
                bessie = bessie + 1
                if bessie == 3:
                    await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='some id'),
                                              '<@&some channel>some text!')
                    print("available")
                    bessie = 0
                    waittime = 10
            else:
                bessie = 0
        else:
            wachttijd = wachttijd - 1

client.run("token")
```

Comment: You need to use `await availability()`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not one hundred percent certain about this however, after some research and as according to the code I viewed on [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652147/using-find-all-in-bs4-to-get-text-as-a-list)  it might be because you are not awaiting response.text.

Try adding the await keyword in front of response.text:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "lxml")
```

Also **don't use time.sleep()** when using discord.py, instead use `await asyncio.sleep(seconds)`

You'll want to avoid blocking whenever possible as it can cause your bot to freeze.  You can read more about it at the ["FAQ" section of the discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean).