# RuntimeError (never awaited) while using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want add to my bot an poll command, which takes an `opt1` and `opt2` parameters, add two reactions to embed, and users have `expir` time to vote, then it send an message which option had more votes, but I have an error: `RuntimeError: coroutine 'poll.<locals>.whowin' was never awaited`. I don't know how to fix it! I tried some solutions, but they didn't work. Here's my code:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 45, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def poll(ctx, title, opt1, opt2, expir):
    try:
        expir = float(expir)
        if expir > 120:
            await ctx.send('Expiration time cannot be greater than 120 seconds.')
            return False
    except:
        await ctx.send('Error while converting `expir` parameter.')
        return False
    pollEmbed=discord.Embed(
        title=title,
        description='React with role below:',
        colour=discord.Colour.blue()
    )
    pollEmbed.add_field(name='Option 1', value=opt1)
    pollEmbed.add_field(name='Option 2', value=opt2)
    thisEmbed = await ctx.send(embed=pollEmbed)
    await discord.Message.add_reaction(thisEmbed, emoji='1\U000020e3')
    await discord.Message.add_reaction(thisEmbed, emoji='2\U000020e3')

    async def whowin():
        if len(users1) > len(users2):
            await ctx.send('People most voted for: {0}'.format(opt1))
            return True
        elif len(users1) < len(users2):
            await ctx.send('People most voted for: {0}'.format(opt2))
            return True
        else:
            await ctx.send('There\'s a tie!')
            return True

    pollTimer = Timer(expir, whowin)
    pollTimer.start()

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if discord.Reaction.message == thisEmbed:
        if discord.Reaction.emoji == '1\U000020e3':
            users1.append(user)
        else:
            users2.append(user)
```

I though I knew the answer for second error (NameError): I tried to make `thisEmbed` global. This fixed it for now, but still having `RuntimeError`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python discord bot - coroutine was never awaited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954196/python-discord-bot-coroutine-was-never-awaited)

Comment: Yeah, but this question was asked a long time ago and I fixed it. I don't use the bot anyway, but thanks for the link to the also answered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you've given, I'm not sure what `Timer` is doing with the second parameter, but because `whowin` is a coroutine (i.e. `async def`), you'll need to call and await it:

```py
pollTimer = Timer(expir, await whowin())
```

However, if you're passing the function into your `Timer` class, then I'm guessing that you didn't await it in there.